# Cant access uploaded files in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload, storage

I'm building my first laravel project, so I don't have much expirience.
I have this form for uploading multiple files.

```
{!! Form::open(array('id' => 'upload', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'url' => 'upload', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}
        {!! Form::file('files[]', array('multiple'=>true)) !!}
        {{  Form::submit('upload', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block')) }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Than I save the files in a controller like this

```
public function postUpload(Request $request) {
    $path = "public/documents/";
    if ($request->files) {
        foreach ($request->files as $file) {
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->storeAs($path, $fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to make a link to open the file - It says the file doesn't exist

```
<a href= {{storage_path('file.pdf') }}>click</a>
```

I've tried few different ways I could find on the internet but none of them worked for me.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check you path, storage_path is different that public_path.
I guess you're saving your file at your public_path()/documents and are trying to download your file from storage_path().

Try to change this:

```
<a href="{{storage_path('file.pdf')}}">click</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="{{public_path()}}/documents/file.pdf">click</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But no the files are actually being stored to the storage directory. I even did the symlink to link it to public folder but no help. I think its gonna be some silly thing. Im running it on homestead if it is relevant information.

the link you provided gives me this URL -> http://katastr.app/home/vagrant/code/katastr/public/documents/file.pdf